# Debug symbols performance issues (FFDA)

Tags: .net, debugging

I have a question about debug symbols in .NET environments, especially ASP.NET. I know that compiling in `Debug` mode prevents the code from being optimized, thus losing potential performance boosts.

However, debug symbols can prove useful if I want to perform FFDA, ie. when I get an exception from a deployed application I can still see the line numbers in its stack trace once I log it.

So, my questions are:

1. Do debug symbols slow down the application continuously during its normal lifecycle? Or is it the same as running a non-optimized code without symbols?
2. When are they used by the framework (ie. when does the slow-down occur)? I know for sure when an exception is thrown, but are there other situations?
3. Would you suggest me to do like Microsoft did: compile the application in Release mode but with symbols so I get optimization at the cost of having approximate line numbers in stack traces?

Explaining question 2: my main concern is about ASP.NET pages. If the page cycle runs well, I wouldn't like any performance decrease to occur so my server can have a better throughput, but when something bad happens (ie. unhandled exception) I want to pay the cost of performance decrease in ordert to get a better stack trace, especially for all the times I had to debug Mono.

My goal is to ease investigating bugs in applications that have been already deployed into their real-world scenario and that log any problem that needs attention.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Because I don't have a large-scale application to test, and I'm *pretty* sure that other people did studies on the impact of debug symbols

Comment: PSA: I was curious and looked it up: It appears that FFDA refers to Field Failure Data Analysis.

Comment: Is there a field-failure-data-analysis tag already?

Comment: I don't get the problem.  If your app is so unstable that you need line number info to diagnose the problems it has, how many Real Users are actually using your app with a happy non-500 outcome?  Debug it first.

Comment: Hans, you missed the point. Nobody deploys an application if not after a severe testing. However, as software engineering suggests, you can't predict you don't have bugs when you switch to production environment. First of all, **I don't currently have any application with such sympthoms**, my question is for future development. The point is that, *in case the application shows problems* I would like to make debugging as cheapest as possible without possibly interfering with runtime operation. (continued)

Comment: Obviously, debug symbols and full stack traces are not the only way you get such cheaper debug. You may need, in general, a proper logging too. To say it shorter, there are lots of aspects for an easy-to-maintain application to take into account. Debug symbols, and that's what my question aims to, may be part of those aspects. But, I ask, at what cost?